# Цикл while . Использование переменных

Tags: python

```
total = 0.00
price = input("Введите цену товара (пустая строка для выхода): ")
while price != '':
    total = float(price) + total
    price = input("Введите цену товара (пустая строка для выхода): ")
print("Полная сумма к оплате: ", total)
a = total * 100 % 5
print(a)
```

Не получается использовать total из цикла для дальнейшего  расчета. Использует  total = 0.00. В чем ошибка?

Comment: Порядок-то правильный? Я бы `total = float(price) + total` и `price = input("Введите цену товара (пустая строка для выхода): ")` поменял местами

Comment: спасибо ,попробую

Comment: Считаем, сколько центов осталось бы, если бы мы оплатили всю покупку 5–центовыми
 монетами. Это a = total * 100 % 5. Но использует total = 0.00 почему то

Comment: Спасибо.  Попробовала - не работает.

Comment: На каких данных вы пробуете? Если ввести, скажем, `1.23` и `3.45` то в результате выдает `3.0` - как раз 3 цента. В этой реализации предполагается, что цена вводится в доларах, где дробная часть это центы. В этом случае все работает. Если у вас `total` - это целое число, то это значит что сумма в доларах без центов и такую сумму можно всегда заплатить 5-центовыми монетами без остатка.

Comment: Огромное спасибо,  Роман . Вы все правильно написали . Я вчера с этим разобралась .